# Determine how many changes pulled using Azure Mobile App Service?

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

In my offline-sync Xamarin.Forms mobile app, I want to inform the user that new stuff is available for review. To do that I need to know when CHANGES are pulled via `PullAsync()`.

I can do a `countRecordsAfterPull() - countRecordsBeforePull()` but that will only tell me the number of NEW records. I also need to know the number of UPDATED records. (And if some records were soft DELETED, they should not interfere with these counts.)

And of course, I need references to all those records, so I can work with them.

*Can this be done?*

Comment: For the push case there's a handy `client.SyncContext.PendingOperations` property (though it only gives a *count* rather than references to the entities staged for pushing). For the pull case I haven't discovered anything similar.

Comment: I normally build that logic into the data and use Incremental sync, filtering the sync/data via `updatedAt` and `Version` fields to determine what is changed.

Comment: @SushiHangover Hmm I suppose that works, but is a lot of effort for something so straightforward... Is there no built-in feature for this?

Comment: Not anyway I know of, its your data, so depending upon how it is structured/changed/sync'd will determine how and when to display those changes to the user. i.e. In one app I have a "Newest/Updated" tab that filters the inbound changes by updateat/version *and* an application specific data column. In another, the actual data itself is timestamped within a change log (not the added Azure sync fields) and we build views/sql filters based upon that info... In another we just show an Led-style control that "lights up" if updatedAt <= 48 hours from now...

Comment: @SushiHangover Ahh pity, I guess I've been spoiled by full-fledged ORMs which have these features out of the box! :)

Comment: Hmm might be possible to trap responses [using a client logger](http://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-mobile-dotnet-todo-list-files/blob/master/src/client/MobileAppsFilesSample/Helpers/LoggingHandler.cs#L63) and determining changes via that...

Comment: There isn't anything other than what people have suggested.  Feel free to add a UserVoice request to feedback.azure.com or a GitHub issue requesting a feature.

Comment: Can someone add that ("not possible in current version") as an answer, so I can accept?

Comment: @AdrianHall It is possible, it's just not documented. Full details below.

Comment: @SushiHangover If you're using the managed SDK, we have the functionality built-in now, see the answer below.

Comment: Even I can learn something new - thanks @lindydonna!

Comment: @AdrianHall Azure is now so large it's becoming hard to keep track of it. Just kidding, love what you guys are building, it's truly awesome. And thanks for answering all our boring questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get record change notifications, use the EventManager object that's attached to the MobileServiceClient object and set up the local store track changes during initialization. (Since the feature is only present in .NET Azure Mobile client SDK, there isn't full documentation and samples yet.)

Local store operations can be wired up to the event manager by initializing the local store with tracking options:

```
await client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, StoreTrackingOptions.NotifyLocalAndServerOperations);`
```

You can subscribe to store operation events like so:

```
subscription = client.EventManager.Subscribe<StoreOperationCompletedEvent>(StoreOperationEventHandler);
```

I've just added a wiki page that covers the basics, which will be fleshed out more in the future: [How to get notifications of new records added during Pull operation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/wiki/How-to-get-notifications-of-new-records-added-during-Pull-operation).

Comment: Wow, so glad this is available out of the box! And so many fine-grained options to tinker with, thanks! Like I commented above to @AdrianHall, Azure is amazing.

Comment: I'm using `StoreTrackingOptions.NotifyServerPullOperations` to know whether other clients (or the server) have made inserts or updates. Do one of those enum options also tell me when a record was soft deleted (i.e. deleted by some other client, so when I do a pull, I'll discover that it was soft deleted)?

Comment: After about three years we're waiting for full documentation and samples! I'm afraid after all one day soon you announce the end of it.